# Autopost to existing Facebook page from Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have developed a Wordpress site that is hosted on the client's server. The client does not want to enable SSL on the server, but wants to be able to auto post from WP to an existing FB page. Is this possible? I know there are a couple of awesome plugins but they all require a FB App to be created. The client does not want to do this, they want to use their existing FB page. Me thinks I might be in for some extra coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of APIs available to work with pages:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to do from WP, but there might be a way to do that through the Page API.  Note that working with pages requires you to have a page access_token, which you will need to set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can set their facebook page up with this plugin: https://www.facebook.com/networkedblogs. It will allow for blog posts to be automatically posted on a facebook page.